# collection view no margin on right

Tags: swift, cell, margin, collectionview, spacing

I have a collection with two column exactly.
The image is as given below:
[image]

The code to make it two column exactly is:

```
 if let layout = alllistcollview?.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout{
                    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 10
                    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 10
                    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: 10)
                    let size = CGSize(width:(alllistcollview!.bounds.width-30)/2, height: 200)
                    layout.itemSize = size
        }
```

Also,in the storyboard the cell spacing is as follows:
[image]

The issue is that the right side spacing has not appeared for the second column.
Also,some part of the cell seem to be cut off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to implement UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

After that add this function like this

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let lay = collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
        let widthPerItem = collectionView.frame.width / 2 - lay.minimumInteritemSpacing
        
        return CGSize(width:widthPerItem, height:150)
    }
```

I define 150 for height. Don't mind that

Comment: I agree.I added the flowlayout code first in viewdidload and then added these flowlayout delegates.Then it worked as expected.